# How to get source code of python import module definition in visual studio code

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm debugging python source code  using windows WSL.
Some modules that I import can see the source code and some can't. Why I can't?

Here I try to find out where is the module installed in WSL:

```
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import ansible
>>> ansible.__file__
'/home/boo/projects/ansible/lib/ansible/__init__.py'
>>> import site; site.getsitepackages()
['/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3.8/dist-packages']
>>> cd
KeyboardInterrupt
>>>
```

Here I can see that I can't access :

[image]

Here I can see that I can access :
[image]

I checked whether the python that VSCODE using is same as the one installed.

[image]

And then I checked in the WSL : point to : python3 -> python3.8

```
tst@TEST:~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ansible/cli$  /bin/python3.8
Python 3.8.2 (default, Apr 27 2020, 15:53:34)
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import ansible
>>> ansible.__file__
'/home/tst/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ansible/__init__.py'
```

**SOLUTION:**
set :

```
justMyCode:false
```

in launch.json

Comment: Could you import the module in the VS Code? Just to confirm in case you are not using the correct environment.

Comment: what do you mean ?

Comment: If you look in the status bar, are you absolutely positive that the environment you have selected has ansible installed in it?

Comment: [Documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_justmycode).

Comment: Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and "[mre]" and all their linked pages. Screen shots of errors make it more difficult to help you. [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/128421) and [I downvoted because an image of your exception isn't helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/)
explain.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks! More complete answer for those searching: make sure you have a `launch.json` file inside your `.vscode` folder -- you can create one automatically with these instructions: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging   ... then add `"justMyCode": false,` inside that file.

Comment: *Provide context for links*: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the external resource is unreachable or goes permanently offline.